# I have added button to Fragment, now i am trying to register that button to Javafile of fragment, but its giving me error in java file

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentSlideshowBinding binding;
    public Button btn1,btn2;

    @Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    btn1=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button); // find view by id is giving error
```

---

(Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'SlideshowFragment)

btn2=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);

```
    SlideshowViewModel slideshowViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SlideshowViewModel.class);
    binding = FragmentSlideshowBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
     //  final TextView textView = binding.button;
    //slideshowViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
    return root;
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using view binding you don't need to access your components with `findViewById` method. While using view binding, pressing dot (.) after calling your view binding reference will show you all available components in your layout. You can simply use:

```
btn1 = binding.button;
btn2 = binding.button2;
```

But if you still want to access your components with `findViewById` method you should use it with your root view reference:

```
btn1 = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.button);
btn2 = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.button2);
```